# Grouped bar with 3 series in Excel

Tags: excel, charts

To save time, I added a picture of the graph I am looking to have and my question is simple:

How do I organize the data efficiently in Excel to present the data that way?

I have 2 regions: EMEA and APJ,

I have 2 products: Prod 1 and Prod 2

For every region (major category) I want to present Renewal, Expiration and Renewal Rate for each product - in a total of 2 bars for each region.

You will save my day at work :-)

Thank you
[image]

Comment: I spend a good amount of time there trying to find anything close to what I was looking for prior to posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Set the data up as shown. The dummy has to be named Expired for the legend to work. Create a stacked bar chart with Renewed, Actual Expired, and Expired. Blank fill for actual expired. Create a line graph with no line, only markers for Percent.